# AngularJS: Don't run ng-repeat on DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I got the following problem:

I have a SPA with AngularJS 1.6.1 and using ng-view to implement some views. I have one view where I add the "UniteGallery" with my own directive within an ng-repeat. So the unitegallery gets loaded dynamically 15 times. This works well so far.

However, I have a mobile menu, which I toggle by clicking on a button. This works well, too. I simply set a class for the menu div with ng-class, depending on whether the menu is open or hidden.

This is, ofcourse, changing my dom. My problem is, that with changing the dom, the ng-repeat is run again. This is causing flickering and performance issues.

Is there a way to change the dom without the ng-repeat being run over and over again?

Comment: Provide us with your code

Comment: Code please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the ng-repeat binding, (with the corresponding dom reload) you can use One Time Bindings

Just use

> ::

before the binding, just likes this:

> ng-repeat="photo in ::gallery"

This will make the $scope.gallery be binded to the view only once

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Daniel Santiago's answer: If you wish to hide "flickering" that was mentioned in your question, you should use `ng-cloak`.

More on [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).